# React-native-navigation is not working correctly

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I'm trying to make custom headerLeft button, But the thing is When I'm going to this specific, route without giving any errors or warnings, it is not working.

Here is my react-navigation stack

```
 const Navigator = createStackNavigator({
  Welcome: WelcomeScreen,
  GetStarted: {
    screen: GetStartedScreen,
  },
  CreatePassword: CreatePasswordScreen,
  AlternatePhrase: {
    screen:AlternatePhraseScreen,
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => {
      return {
        headerLeft:<HeaderBackButton onPress={navigation.navigate("WelcomeScreen")} />
      }
    }
  },
  ConfirmPhrase: ConfirmPhraseScreen,
  FanwallyAgreement: FanwallyAgreementScreen,
  ImportWallet: ImportWalletFieldsScreen,
  Main: MainScreen,
  TokenDeposit,
});
```

Every other screens are working perfectly its just this one

```
`
  AlternatePhrase: {
        screen:AlternatePhraseScreen,
        navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => {
          return {
            headerLeft:<HeaderBackButton onPress={navigation.navigate("WelcomeScreen")} />
          }
        }
      },
`
```

Any suggestions on what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're using old react-navigation version. If possible upgrade to > 5.x

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
onPress={() => navigation.navigate("WelcomeScreen")}
```